# Difference between sigma protocol, Schnorr protocol, Pedersen commitment

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments, sigma-protocol

Could you explain the difference between sigma protocol, Schorr protocol with examples. What is the advantage of using commit-and-prove zero knowledge proof over general zero knowledge proof?

Comment: As I know, Schnorr protocol is an instance of $\Sigma$ protocol which is a kind of interactive proofs.

Comment: And the commitment scheme always owns hidding and binding properties, which could meet zero-knowledge and soundness requirements for zero knowledege proofs/arguments. Thus, when constructing a proof/argument system, we always take various commitment schemes into the system.